# Tracking forwarded traffic

Tags: nat, traffic-management

I have following set up :

a machine with a public IP with several machines with static IP behind it (NAT).

How would I monitor the traffic they generate on a per IP basis (the LAN ip to which traffic gets forwarded) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use some netflow sensor (for example fprobe, ipcad) and then export it to some collector. I used UTM5, but it's paid. I think there should be some free netflow collectors. For momentary snapshot of traffic you can use iftop.

Answer (score 1):

If your gateway box is running Linux, you could use an `iptables` `-j LOG` parameter.  Something like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j LOG
```

You'd then have to configure your `syslog` to send that log data somewhere where the I/O won't hurt the process.  You could also limit the I/O required by only logging tcp connection packets.  Just replace the above with this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp --syn -j LOG
```